# Sort numpy array by order of matching values of another array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array by another array that has matching indexes but in a different order.

```
In: array1
Out: array([123, 323, 142, 532, 563, 256])

In: array2
Out: array([323, 563, 256, 142, 123, 532])
```

I'm not sure what to do to make `array2` get reordered to be in the same order as `array1`. So I would like for the end product to look like this:

```
In: array1
Out: array([123, 323, 142, 532, 563, 256])

In: array2
Out: array([123, 323, 142, 532, 563, 256])
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can using `numpy` broadcast with `np.where`

```
a2[np.where(a2==a1[:,None])[1]]
Out[88]: array([123, 323, 142, 532, 563, 256])
```